# Can a function ever be locally invertible at an inflection point?

Tags: calculus

Suppose that we have a function $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ that is defined on a closed, bounded, and continuous set. Suppose further that there are one or more inflection points in this set.

Is it possible for $f$ to be locally invertible at any of the inflection points? My intuition tells me no, but I don't know how to show this in a rigorous manner if it is indeed true.

Comment: What about $f(x) = x^3$ on $[-1,1]$?

Comment: Oh yeah, I didn't think about that scenario. What about if it's a point of concavity/convexity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, all functions $$f(x) = x^{2n+1}$$  for $n\ge 1$ are such functions.

Their  inflection points are at $x=0$ and they are locally invertible at $x=0.$